# How to load external script like Twitter widgets in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to load a twitter widget in meteor like:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>&quot;Curiosity Finds Iron Meteorite on Mars&quot; <a href="http://t.co/qh6f1ITd7b">http://t.co/qh6f1ITd7b</a></p>&mdash; Daniel Fischer (@dfischer) <a href="https://twitter.com/dfischer/statuses/489240003927887872">July 16, 2014</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But this just loads as plaintext.

I tried creating a package:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "External script"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use(['templating'], 'client');

  api.add_files('widget.html', 'client');
});
```

with widget.html having:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></head>
```

But no luck. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Try taking out the async and putting the script tag before the html body. It might be loading afterwards. Also, is there any JS errors to show for?

Comment: That didn't work @LancePioch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template (let's call it widgetTemplate), where the widget should be rendered use the following function (try / catch just to be safe):

```
Template.widgetTemplate.rendered = function () {
    try {
        twttr.widgets.load();
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

Same can be used for facebook widgets (share like etc) - `FB.XFBML.parse()`

Make sure you have widgets.js loaded in head - sync or async.

For async loading use this code in 'head':

```
<script>
    ! function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing. .load() and .parse() were exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Why do we need try and catch?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pattern for asynchronously loading a script and reactively knowing when it's loaded or has failed to load. I created a meteor project with the two files as given below and was able to see your tweet with proper styling.

twitter-widgets-load.html:

```
<head>
  <title>twitter-widgets-load</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> tweet}}
  {{> loadStatus}}
</body>

<template name="tweet">
  <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
    <p>&quot;Curiosity Finds Iron Meteorite on
      Mars&quot;
      <a href="http://t.co/qh6f1ITd7b">http://t.co/qh6f1ITd7b</a>
    </p>&mdash; Daniel Fischer (@dfischer)
    <a href="https://twitter.com/dfischer/statuses/489240003927887872">
      July 16, 2014</a>
  </blockquote>
</template>

<template name="loadStatus">
  {{#if SEql "twitterWidgetsLoaded" false}}
    Oh no! The Twitter Widgets library couldn't load!
  {{else}}
    {{#unless SEql "twitterWidgetsLoaded" true}}
      Loading Twitter Widgets...
    {{/unless}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

twitter-widgets-load.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  var twitterWidgetsLoadedCallback = function(){
    Session.set("twitterWidgetsLoaded", true);
  }; 

  var twitterWidgetsErrorCallback = function(error){
    Session.set("twitterWidgetsLoaded", false);
    console.log(error);
  };

  //Generate a script tag
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
  script.onload = twitterWidgetsLoadedCallback;
  script.onerror = twitterWidgetsErrorCallback;

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    //Load the script tag
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(script);
  });

  UI.registerHelper("SEql", function (key, val) {
    return Session.equals(key, val);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index.html for a layout for Iron Router, then you would want to put that script tag into the  tag of the website. I'm not 100%, but I think you can puts  tags anywhere in the templates and they will be glommed together and delivered to the browser.  Just let them live outside any  tags.

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-45XXXXXX-1', 'fantasyhub.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
</head>

<template name="layout">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <p class="browser-warning"><strong><i class="icon-exclamation-sign"></i> Warning</strong> - You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/" target="_blank">upgrade your browser</a> to properly view this website.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  {{> yield region='header'}}
  {{> yield}}
  {{> yield region='footer'}}
</template>
```

That covers things like google analytics.  The other option is to put something into Meteor.startup that would inject the scripts into the html for you. I've pulled this from the Social Sharing package, [shareIt](https://github.com/Differential/shareit):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  var id, js, ref;
  window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var fjs, js, t;
    t = void 0;
    js = void 0;
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = {
      _e: [],
      ready: function(f) {
        return t._e.push(f);
      }
    });
  })(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

I would highly recommend checking out the [ShareIt package](https://github.com/Differential/shareit) if you are trying to do twitter and facebook stuff, as it gives you all the meta tags to support things like Open Graph and Twitter Cards out of the box.

Comment: Putting it into the head doesn't work. It needs to instantiate the widget somehow after load...  not sure how to trigger this? Same idea if you had social share widgets I think.

Comment: I've update the post above, take a look at the new example I added and see if it helps.